# Assigning an alias to SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

In the library database there's a patrons table listing all the users of the library. The columns are id, first_name, last_name, address, email, library_id and zip_code.

Generate a list of strings that are in the following format: Andrew Chalkley .

Concatenate the first name, last name and email address for all users.
Alias it to to_field. This will be used in the "To" field in email marketing.

my code:

```
SELECT first_name || last_name || email AS "to_field" 
FROM patrons;
```

Comment: Use the `concat()` function in MySQL, unless you have the setting that allows the `||` operator.  I view this as a typographical error and vote to close such questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use mysql [CONCAT_WS()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) in your case (This will concatenate all non NULL values using the specified separator):

```
SELECT
    CONCAT_WS(" ", first_name, last_name, email) AS to_field
FROM
    patrons
```

Comment: this will actually work in sql-lite:   > SELECT first_name || " " || last_name || " " || "<" ||email || ">" AS to_field FROM patrons;